# probability that two of these boxes contain exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is

Tags: probability

> If $10$ different balls are to be placed in $4$ distinct boxes at random,  then the probability that two of these boxes contain exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is

What I tried:

Total number of ways $\displaystyle 4^{10}$

probability that two of these boxes contain exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is 
 $\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2^5$

So required probability $$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2^5}{4^{10}}$$

But answer given as $\displaystyle \frac{945}{2^{10}}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504737/10-balls-are-to-be-placed-randomly-in-4-boxes-what-is-the-probability-that-any

Comment: The answer $945/2^{10}$ looks incorrect as @paw88789 stated below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the following variants to distribute balls into the boxes: 
$$
\underbrace{2+3+0+5}_{A_1}, \quad \underbrace{2+3+1+4}_{A_2}, \quad \underbrace{2+3+2+3}_{A_3}.
$$
And the probability that two of these box contain exactly $2$ and $3$ balls is the sum of probabilities for these variants to distribute balls: 
$$
\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A_1)+\mathbb P(A_2)+\mathbb P(A_3).
$$

Find $\mathbb P(A_1)$. There are $\dfrac{10!}{2!\cdot 3!\cdot 0!\cdot 5!}$ ways to chose balls for each box and $4!$ ways to arrange boxes: box for $2$ balls can be chosen by $4$ ways, box for $3$ balls - by $3$ ways, for $0$ balls - by $2$ ways and the rest box is for $5$ balls. So 
$$
\mathbb P(A_1) = \frac{10! \cdot 4!}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 0!\cdot 5! \cdot 4^{10}} = \frac{60480}{4^{10}},
$$
The same way 
$$
\mathbb P(A_2) = \frac{10! \cdot 4!}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 1!\cdot 4! \cdot 4^{10}} = \frac{302400}{4^{10}}.
$$
For $A_3$, we need to chose pair of boxes for two balls by $\binom{4}{2}$ ways instead of $4!$. So 
$$
\mathbb P(A_3) = \frac{10! \cdot \binom{4}{2}}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 2!\cdot 3! \cdot 4^{10}} = \frac{151200}{4^{10}}.
$$
Finally
$$
\mathbb P(A)=\frac{514080}{4^{10}}=\frac{16065}{2\cdot 4^7}\approx 0,490264893.
$$

Comment: Yes, I see your point and I think that your answer is the correct one. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The given answer is wrong! The correct one has been found by NCh.

If the question was: find the probability that box 1 contains exactly 3 balls and box 2 contains exactly 2 balls then result is
$$p:=\frac{\binom{10}{3}\cdot\binom{7}{2}\cdot 2^5}{4^{10}}=\frac{315}{2^{12}}$$
$\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose the balls  to be put in box 1, $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to choose the balls to be put in box 2, and $2^5$ ways to place the $5$ remaining balls in box 3 and 4.

If we multiply the probability $p$ by $4\cdot 3$, the number ordered couples of boxes, we find the given result
$$\frac{945}{2^{10}}.$$

Comment: Over counted some cases? E.g. a 3, 3, 2, 2 distribution?

Comment: @RobertZ Check your logic for $2$ balls, $2$ boxes and probability that "one of two boxes containes exactly one ball". It will be: $2$ ways to chose box, $2$ ways to chose ball for this box, one way to put the rest bal into the rest box, $\mathbb P(\ldots)=\frac44=1$. And really this probability is $\frac12$.

Comment: Probability above 90 percent seems too high, for any interpretation of the problem. I remain highly suspicious of the  answer that OP said was the given answer. I did a paper and pencil calculation and it looked like cases of 3,3,3,1 and 4,4,1,1 and 5,4,1,0 distributions together had a more than 10 percent chance of occurring.